# Yii2 widget textarea(\yii\imperavi\Widget) defaul

Tags: forms, yii2, widget, textarea, field

I need set the post value to textarea, but textarea is not usual textarea, I use widget `\yii\imperavi\Widget` textarea and because now I not understand how I can add a default value.

```
    echo $form->field($model, $property)->widget(
    \yii\imperavi\Widget::className(), [
        'plugins' => ['fullscreen', 'fontcolor'],
        'value' => 'Hello World!',
        'options' => [
            'minHeight' => 400,
            'maxHeight' => 400,
            'buttonSource' => true,
            'convertDivs' => false,
            'removeEmptyTags' => false,
            'imageUpload' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/file-storage/upload-imperavi'])
        ]
    ]
)->label( $label ) ?>
```

This is not working

```
'value' => 'Hello World!'
```

Maybe you had such problems and know how to solve? ))

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your widget is just a reach-text editor called "Redactor". It's purpose is not to set a "default" value to underlying text field of the form but to support it with rich editing capabilities.

What you need is to set a default value to underlying text filed - regardless a widget sitting upon this or not!

The way to provide a default value in Yii2 is to initialize a model supporting this active text field with it's attribute set to given value rather than default "null".

That can be done best within a model class itslef. I presume your model class is extending ActiveRecord class:

```
class MyModel extends yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init(); // this is obligatory!
        $this->attribute_name = "My default text";
    }
}
```

Where "attribute_name" is actually the name of the attribute you should further use in your ActiveField:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'attribute_name')
->widget(\yii\imperavi\Widget::className(), [...]);
```

I hope that might be helpful!

Comment: I need to set value from the POST, so the usual methods do not help.
Well, all thanks for the answer )) If you have other options without a model, I'm listening.

Comment: The code you've provided clearly shows YOU DO USE a model:

    echo $form->field($model, $property)->widget(

Then, what is the question about?

- is it about how to set a default walue for a text filed
- or how to set it to a value from POST?

In Yii2 you can use the following in the controller class:

    if ($model->load() && $model->validate() {
        return $this->render('my_view', $model);
    }

to feed a model with a POST data, and then pass it to the view. 

Have a look here for more detais:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load()-detail

Answer (score 0):

In order to it begin to work, you need to initialize **value** in "options":

```
echo $form->field($model, $property)->widget(
    \yii\imperavi\Widget::className(), [
        'plugins' => ['fullscreen', 'fontcolor'],
        'options' => [
            'value' => 'Hello World!',
            'minHeight' => 400,
            'maxHeight' => 400,
            'buttonSource' => true,
            'convertDivs' => false,
            'removeEmptyTags' => false,
            'imageUpload' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/file-storage/upload-imperavi'])
        ]
    ]
)->label( $label ) ?>
```